# Why does data briefly flash in a .NET 8.0 Blazor project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm working with the .NET 8.0 Blazor projects and my components briefly flash before appearing. I used the new Blazor Web App template.

[image]

Some form of a flash happens regardless of what `@rendermode` (`InteractiveAuto`, `InteractiveWebAssembly`, or `InteractiveServer`) I'm using and whether or not the `[StreamRendering]` attribute is present. The location of the component between the two Blazor projects also has no effect. Additionally, the component takes twice as long to load, from the 2 second `await Task.Delay(2000);` simulated delay to 4 seconds.

If I remove `@rendermode` completely, the flashing does cease. I do, however, need to use `@rendermode InteractiveAuto` because I modified the Weather component to have the interactive [Quickgrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/quickgrid?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

What is the cause and solution for this issue?

In a [Tim Corey's video](https://youtu.be/walv3nLTJ5g?t=2060), he encounters a similar situation and mentions at 34:47 that development mode "turns off a lot of things". Could it be something to do with that? At 37:06 he demonstrates the equivalent of `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly` and confuses even himself by the behavior.

Weather.razor

```
@page "/weather"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid
@attribute [StreamRendering]
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>
<h1 class="text-muted">Render @(OperatingSystem.IsBrowser() ? "Wasm" : "Server")</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{

    <QuickGrid Class="table" Items="forecasts" Pagination="paginationState">
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(forecast => forecast.Date)" Sortable="true" InitialSortDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(forecast => forecast.TemperatureC)" Sortable="true" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(forecast => forecast.TemperatureF)" Sortable="true" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(forecast => forecast.Summary)" Sortable="true" />
    </QuickGrid>
    <Paginator State="paginationState" />
}

@code {
    private IQueryable<WeatherForecast>? forecasts;
    PaginationState paginationState = new PaginationState { ItemsPerPage = 5 };

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate streaming rendering
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 15).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
            }).AsQueryable();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `@attribute [StreamRendering]`, it is only useful for SSR. Not sure if that helps though.

Comment: Read the following commentary of mine that may provide some insights into the hazards of `InteractiveAuto` - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/Going-For-Broke.md

Comment: @ℍℍ `@attribute [StreamRendering]` is still useful with `@rendermode InteractiveAuto` as SSR occurs on first render until WASM is downloaded. And as I mentioned, `[StreamRendering]` does not stop the flash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing double rendering with the combination of "Interactive Server Render Mode" and "Stream Rendering"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515282/preventing-double-rendering-with-the-combination-of-interactive-server-render-m)

Comment: Have you tried the suggested way? Does that resolved your issue?

Comment: Can you please clarity what render mode you have set on the `Routes` component in `App.razor`?  Can you show your `App.razor` in the question.

Comment: @BrianParker I did end up finding a solution elsewhere that's also mentioned in that post, which is to disable prerendering. However, while this resolves the issue, I still don't understand the cause of it or where having prerendering enabled is useful.